# Approximate $e^{0.01} \sin(0.02)$ by using its linearization

Tags: calculus, approximation

$f(x,y) = e^x \sin(y)$

$f_x = e^x \sin(y)$

$f_y = e^x \cos(y)$

$L(x,y) = f(0,0) + f_x(0,0)x +f_y(0,0)y$

Solving:

$f(0,0) = e^0 \sin(0) = 0$

$f_x(0,0)x = e^0 \sin(0) \cdot x = 0$

$f_y(0,0)y = e^0 \cos(0) \cdot y = y$

So L(x,y) = y

yet [here it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkJiP.png) says $1+y$, how come?

Comment: it's probably a typo.

Comment: @KonKan perhaps you should make that a community answer (I'd do it but apparently I can't on mobile).